# Invert convolution rule for the Laplace transform?

Tags: convolution

For the Laplace transform, there is a rule to handle convolutions:
$$\mathcal{L}\{u*v\}=\mathcal{L}\{u\}\cdot\mathcal{L}\{v\}.$$
In Fourier transform, there is a similar formular and furthermore, there is a formular to invert this convolution and multiplication theorem. Is there something similar for the Laplace transform, like
$$\mathcal{L}\{u\cdot v\} = f(U * V)$$
for any or certain classes of functions $U, V$ in general or under certain conditions?

Comment: Are you looking for $$(u*v)(t)=\int_0^t u(\tau)v(t-\tau)\,d\tau$$?

Comment: No, I would like to have something like
$$\mathcal{L}\{u\cdot v\}=\;?\;\cdot (U*V)$$

Comment: I am not really sure there exists such identity, but I’ll leave others prove this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, after doing some research, it seems that there is no general, simply form to solve my problem. Thanks for all contributions.